# How can you edit like a "config.json" in c# on command. (Keep in mind, the bot uses config.json for it's ticket and serverip)

Tags: c#

How can you edit like a "config.json" in c# on command? (Keep in mind, the bot uses config.json for its discord token and a server-ip)

I want to change the "server-ip" part.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you haven't already, I'd recommend that you read the [Ask] section of the Help Center. There, you'll see it's extremely helpful to the volunteers on this site that you provide [mcve] within your question!

Comment: Json is a form of text, but you can read in json, edit values and write back all the json.. What did you try?

Answer (score -1):

I can't answer in detail without more context, but if you want to edit JSON in C# then you will probably want to use the Newtonsoft.Json (also known as JSON.NET) package which you can download via NuGet.

Comment: I have newtonsoft.Json, what context do you need? I'll offer it to you when I'm home, but what function would you use to do that?

Comment: Here's a link. You will need both the Deserialize and Serialize functions

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

(I don't know why people are being so downvote-happy. Stack Overflow is not an inclusive site, especially for newcomers like yourself...)

Comment: I was confused because you were talking about "the bot" as though it had already been explained. I'm guessing you're making a Discord bot? Either explain that or leave it out entirely.

Comment: It's a discord bot, yes. obviously, People are salt I guess, no clue.